# Wrong data populating

Tags: informatica

Source datatype is string date format is DD-MON-YY.IN EXPRESSION  OUTPUT PORT datatype is date/time here informatica taking default date format but I need this format 'DD-MM-YY'

To_date(col,DD-MM-YY) it's give wrong data

Answer (score 0):

try `MON` instead of `MM` while doing to date

```
to_date(col,,'DD-MON-YY')
```